# ngb-datepicker and Angular 4: add button inside the datepicker box

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'd like to add a button inside the datepicker box, something like "Today" which is clickable and selects the current date;

From what i've seen in the documentation there's only the `[dateTemplate]` option which seems to affect the date elements inside the datepicker. [[custom day view]](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) 
Is there another attribute or some other way one can use to add a button inside this box?